# send input to netcat and save output

Tags: linux, centos, netcat

I am trying to send a command to `netcat` which will result into an output and I want to save that output to a file.

```
while true; do echo "showHistory userx"; done | nc -w1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 2222 > out.txt &
```

I tried a lot of google searches and read a lot of stackexchange questions but could not solve it. I played around with `while`, `tee`, `mkfifo` but no luck.

The file `out.txt` remains blank but has a lot of `NUL` chars

Edit: I have updated `showhistory` to `showHistory userx` in order to highlight that it is a command to be supplied over telnet/netcat session

Comment: You might want to use `&>` instead of `>` to send both `stdout` and `stderr` to the file. Otherwise you have to be more precise about what is not working.

Comment: If I'm guessing right, your problem is that file is empty, right ? Quote from bash manual:"Background  processes  which
       attempt  to  read  from  (write to when stty tostop is in effect) the terminal are sent a SIGTTIN
       (SIGTTOU) signal by the kernel's terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process".  There's your reason - get rid of `&` part

Comment: And I don't know why that `showhistory` is needed, but `yes showhistory` does the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've found smth like that

for port scanning output(ex. my router)

```
nc -zv 192.168.0.1 1-1000 2>&1 | grep open | tee report.txt
```

read a report

```
cat report.txt
```

output

```
_gateway [192.168.0.1] 80 (http) open 
_gateway [192.168.0.1] 22 (ssh) open
```

In snapshot[image]

Comment: the image is no longer available